# nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the following Ingress section:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tb-ingress
  namespace: thingsboard
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/v1/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: tb-http-transport
          servicePort: http
      - path: /static/rulenode/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: tb-node
          servicePort: http
      - path: /static/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: tb-web-ui
          servicePort: http
      - path: /index.html.*
        backend:
          serviceName: tb-web-ui
          servicePort: http
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: tb-web-ui
          servicePort: http
```

However, this does not seem to be working. GKE gives me an

> Invalid path pattern, invalid

error.

Comment: Please provide other parts of your ingress if any and please show what exactly is not working. Btw, read more here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/

Comment: I've added the complete ingress section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me, you forgot to specify `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation. If you don't specify any `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` - GKE will consider using its own ingress which does not support regexps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, adding kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" does not change the error.

Comment: do you have nginx ingress installed in your cluster?

Comment: Not quite following your last question. I applied the config from my question, is there anything else I need to do to make nginx work?

Comment: You applied annotations which work only with Nginx Ingress. You cannot expect those annotations to work with GKE ingress. So got this annotations to work - you must install https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx which will create another public Load Balancer.